# Translating natural language to propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have been given the following assignment:

Charles is rich or clever.

If Charles was clever, he'd have a job.

But, Charles doesn't have a job, so he must be rich.

The translation I gave (verified by the book) is:

r = rich, c = clever, j = job

```
r OR c, c IMPLIES j, NOT j ENTAIL r
```

which translates to:

```
r OR c 1.
c IMPLIES j 2.
NOT j 3.
```

The book gives a rather elaborate solution.

Why can't I just:

```
r 4. OR-ELIMINATION of 1
```

?

Comment: Hi, sorry if this was off topic. May I ask which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't immediately deduce $r$ because the first premise isn't a conjunction; it's a disjunction $$r \lor c\tag{1}$$ and so you can't invoke $\land$-elimination to conclude $r$ from premise $(1)$.

**Edit:**

You've misunderstood what $\lor$-elimination involves and/or requires. It certainly does not license you to conclude either $r$ or $c$ from $r\lor c$ alone. What happens if $r = F$ and $c = T$? In that case, $r\lor c$ is true, because $c$ is true. So concluding $r$ from $r\lor c\,$ is, in fact, a fallacy. All you know is that one, or perhaps both, disjuncts hold.

Instead, you can assume $r$, which immediately implies $r$, and then assume $c$ from which you'll be able to deduce $r$, and then by $\lor$-elimination, conclude therefore $r$.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry, fixed that, I mean OR-ELIMINATION not AND-ELIMINATION

Comment: Or elimnation doesn't work that way. Or-elimination is not a ticket to grab $r$ from $r\lor c$. In general, for all you know, $r\lor c$ can be true, even though $r$ might be false (e.g., if $c = T$).